# User' object has no attribute 'make_password'

Tags: django, authentication, case-sensitive

what is the error with set_password
/base/backends.py in authenticate

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend

class CaseInsensitiveModelBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self,request,username=None,password=None,**Kwargs):
        UserModel=get_user_model()
        if username is None:
            username=Kwargs.get(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)
        try:
            case_insensitive_username_field='{}__iexact'.format(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)
            user = UserModel._default_manager.get(**{case_insensitive_username_field:username})
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            UserModel().set_paassword(password)
        else:
            if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
                return user
```

i try to put make_password but not working

Comment: am try set_password and make_password same error

Comment: It is `set_password`, without double `a`...